# Google API access from Windows Service

Tags: c#, google-api, windows-services

I implemented Google apps API in a MVC Web app, to access for Admin SDK to add/remove users from Google apps account. 
In my web app, first the user needs to authenticate with the Google Apps account (OAuth 2.0), then I store the accesstoken and refreshtoken in the database storage. After that,Admin SDK API calls to add/remove user functionality in the web app uses the "offline" mode as it does not pop up the consent screen.

But I need to use my database token storage(accesstokens/refreshtokens) for the authentication. How can I do this?

My requirement is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332283/accessing-google-drive-from-windows-service). But the issue is that the content is modified and URLs to those samples are no longer there.

Answer (score 1):

I could not accomplish this task in a nice way, I had to do few hacks. (In fact as long as the access token is live this can be done, problem occurs is when we need to refresh the token).

Finally I implemented a WebAPI project which can handle token refreshing, works pretty much similar to the MVC app. Windows service communicates with the web API project when it requires the API call and get the response after the job done.

Comment: Hi Dhanuka,  I know you posted this question and answer two years ago, but I am hoping you can still help.  In the (hacked) solution that you developed, did the MVC app require IIS?  Can you explain a little more about how you need to configure the machine on which the service will run so that the MVC app will execute?

Comment: Yes, MVC WebAPI was hosted in IIS. Machine that install the windows service should be given access to the Web API endpoint. Just double check whether Google API token refresh whether there is a new way/better way of doing this. When I was doing this if there was a simple endpoint to get the token refreshed I wouldn't do this. Main issue as far as i can remember you need to pass a callback controller to get the refresh token.

Comment: FYI: If I am asked to do this again, I won't use the .Net library, instead use their REST api instead :). Reason is this is pretty easy to understand and meintain. When the .NET wrapper does not support certain low level functions you have to do hacks. Which make things more complicated and hard to maintain.