# How to use google Calendar API in windows Service?

Tags: c#, api, google-calendar-api, credentials

i need to run my application for multiple user google calendar updating. Running on a windows form everything works fine but as soon as i start the windows service that host my application the code stops running while getting google Authorization for the first user. Below the code i have used. Do you have any ideas?
This is my code:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {   
   string credPath = eMail + ".json";   
   credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                       GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                       new[] {CalendarService.Scope.Calendar},
                       "user",
                       CancellationToken.None,
                       new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;


Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);}
```

Comment: Try seeing the result you get... From the Google API. Also take a look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668060/google-api-access-from-windows-service

Comment: What path is the file? It could be that the identity running the service does not have access. Use exception handling. Use logging.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already tried this solution but it doesn' t work. Here https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet there is an explanation of google' s api but in a windows service it doesn't work.

Comment: I think that for this case you should be using [google service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts). Have you looked at them? I don't know if there is an easy fix with user authentication in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have any pratical example of service account' s implementation ? it works also to manage more user concurrently?

Comment: In the end i have launched the program not with windows service but with CLI application and i have automatized it with cobian.

Answer (score 0):

At the end i have not been able to run my application through windows service and so to resolve my problem i have decided to launch my program with a CLI application and to automatize it with Cobian and in this way it works.