# How to use Gmail API in win service

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api

I'm trying to retrieve mail from Gmail. The problem with the below code is, first time it will prompt you to authorize access.

I followed this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet#step_3_set_up_the_sample) for help.

How can I achieve this this using Win services?

Here is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart2.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Gmail API service.
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });


        var re = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
        re.LabelIds = "INBOX";
        re.Q = "is:unread"; //only get unread;

        var res = re.Execute();

        if (res != null && res.Messages != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("there are {0} emails. press any key to continue!", res.Messages.Count);
            Console.ReadKey();

            foreach (var email in res.Messages)
            {
                var emailInfoReq = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", email.Id);
                var emailInfoResponse = emailInfoReq.Execute();

                if (emailInfoResponse != null)
                {
                    String from = "";
                    String date = "";
                    String subject = "";
                    String body = "";
                    //loop through the headers and get the fields we need...
                    foreach (var mParts in emailInfoResponse.Payload.Headers)
                    {
                        if (mParts.Name == "Date")
                        {
                            date = mParts.Value;
                        }
                        else if (mParts.Name == "From")
                        {
                            from = mParts.Value;
                        }
                        else if (mParts.Name == "Subject")
                        {
                            subject = mParts.Value;
                        }

                        if (date != "" && from != "")
                        {
                            if (emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts == null && emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body != null)
                                body = DecodeBase64String(emailInfoResponse.Payload.Body.Data);
                            else
                                body = GetNestedBodyParts(emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts, "");

                            //now you have the data you want....

                        }

                    }

                    //Console.Write(body);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}  --  {1}  -- {2}", subject, date, email.Id);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `first time it will prompt you to authorize access`, that's the point of the authentication. If not how else does it know if you don't sign in?

Comment: how can we achieve this using win service any other way??

Comment: Hi @jacksonjohn , Did you find a solution for windows service and Gmail? I have the same problem and I'm trying to call another application in order to open Google Authorization Access, but it doesn't work.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize OAuth2 to start, Gmail doesn’t support service accounts. "When your application installs it should prompt the user for authentication once then save that authentication. Create a windows service that checks gmail ever x amount of time, if it finds something fire off your console app" as stated in this [tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/how-to-access-gmail-with-c-net/). Also in a related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12332841/5995040), "quickstart application is a simplified command-line app that cuts some corners to make the getting started experience quicker but it can still be used as a starting point for a Windows service."

Answer (score 0):

First-time flow can't be on service code, because you can't interact with the user.

You can try to create an installer and then ask him for credential.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by Service account in Gsuit.
We need to create project, enable API, Create Service account and get p12 file. [Follow this link-Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#callinganapi)

Configure the service account mail id and client Id in your Gsuit Account (check the above link).

Here is my code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plus API - Service Account");
        Console.WriteLine("==========================");

        String serviceAccountEmail = "xxxx@xxxx-xxxx.xx.gserviceaccount.com";

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +
             "xxxxxxxxxx.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom },
               User = "xxxx@xxxxxxx.net"//ur Gsuit Id
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service.
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "xxxxx",
        });
```

For getting the mail use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448193/how-to-retrieve-my-gmail-messages-using-gmail-api/37530785#37530785)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I know it wasn't your case, but don't post code you clearly got from somewhere else claiming it's yours. The proper thing to do is "credit" the author of that code, in which case you now did. Thank you for that!